# Composer: How to setup private Symfony bundles on svn

Tags: svn, symfony, composer-php, unfuddle

I am using svn for hosting my projects on unfuddle.com. All of them share some of my bundles that I would like to keep private.

Example:

I created `d:bundles/ImageBundle` folder and copied the code I already have. Structure is like any other symfony bundle, I have folders Controller, Entity etc inside it. Is it good way of doing it?

What should `ImageBundle/composer.json` have? When I try to install that bundle, I get this error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - The requested package wjb/image-bundle dev could not be found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability....

Even when my programs' composer.json file has `"wjb/image-bundle": "*"` I get it.

My main composer.json also has this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "http://mysvnrepository" ,
        "trunk-path": "ImageBundle",
        "branches-path":false,
        "tags-path": false
    }
]
```

Comment: please review my answer and accept if working otherwise please add information what happened when using stabiity flag @dev :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer says it has found the package put your project requires a higher stability:

```
The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability....
```

To resolve the issue set the minimum stability to dev for that one package in your project's composer.json.

```
"wjb/image-bundle": "*@dev"
```

Read more on stability flags [here](https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html).

You can also set minimum stability in your composer.json for your whole project to one of dev,alpha,beta,rc or stable.
But as this will affect your whole project this is not recommended.

```
// ...
"require" : {
    // ... dependencies here
},
"minimum-stability" : "dev",
 // ...
```